# SwiftUI Screen safe area

Tags: swiftui

Im trying to calculate the screen safe area size in a SwiftUI app launch so I can derive component sizes from the safe area rectangle for iOS devices of different screen sizes.

UIScreen.main.bounds - I can use this at the start but it gives me the total screen and not the safe area

GeometryReader - using this I can get the CGSize of the safe area but I cant find a way to send this anywhere - tried using Notifications and simple functions both of which caused errors

Finally I tried using the .onPreferenceSet event in the initial view then within that closure set a CGSize variable in a reference file, but doing that, for some reason makes the first view  initialise twice. Does anyone know a good way to get the edge insets or the safe area size at app startup?

Comment: Why do you need to send the size of the safe area anywhere?

Comment: Would you show in code instead what are you trying to do and it does not work?

Comment: @pawello2222 - I want to create a file at startup with a list of measurements that other views can reference

Comment: @JohnOfIreland You don't usually need it in SwiftUI. Please share your code, so we can help you.

Comment: that works but it triggers the rest of the ContentView() twice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried this?

You can use `EnvironmentObject` to send the safe area insets anywhere in your code after initializing it in your initial `View`.

This works for me.

```
class GlobalModel: ObservableObject {
    
    //Safe Area size
    @Published var safeArea: (top: CGFloat, bottom: CGFloat)
    
    init() {
        self.safeArea = (0, 0)
    }
}
```

Inside SceneDelegate.

```
let globalModel = GlobalModel()
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(globalModel)
```

Inside your initial view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var globalModel: GlobalModel

    var body: some View {
       ZStack {
          GeometryReader { geo in
             Color.clear
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .onAppear {
                   self.globalModel.safeArea = (geo.safeAreaInsets.top, geo.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                }
          }
        
          SomeView()
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

More simpler solution :

```swift
UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }?.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

or shorter:

```swift
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code formatter and explanation in your answer?

Comment: Thanks for you answer Leonard but I had already accepted an answer a while ago

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use the proxy of the `GeometryReader`! No needs to be dependent to the scene or app delegate or event the UIKit!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Text("\(proxy.safeAreaInsets.top)")
        }
    }
}
```